# Responsive Header Breakpoint

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to change the breakpoint of a website's header.

the theme I installed onto this website has the mobile header breaking at 1139px and below. I want to change it so that it breaks at the standard 1024px (ie 1023px)

> website: https://www.vibrantrealestate.com.au/

normally i just go into the css and change the @media query to the width i want to, but this theme has quite a few @media querys with min-width: 1140px/max-width: 1139px when i searched in the stylesheet so i'm not exactly sure which one I should change. i've tried trying to change them individually through the wordpress customiser, however i'm still a bit stuck for ideas as it isn't changing the appearance. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not modify the theme's original style rules, instead you want to override them.

Although not advisable, this could be as simple as making new @media rules placed at the very bottom of the theme's CSS file, so in theory they override the earlier rules (if you configure the new rules correctly).

However the best thing would be to create a child theme, with the original theme as the parent. This would ensure your changes are wholly separate from the original code; much cleaner/safer/more-organized.

In either case, you'll have to use your brain to setup the new rules so they fully override the originals. You may need to make use of the `!important` flag.

You could make an override that covers a slightly wider range, to make sure your aesthetic changes take hold. e.g. min-width: 1000px/max-width: 1200px; (if the original is min-width: 1140px/max-width: 1139px).

You can't avoid work when doing responsive optimization.